# How to calculate 1.5 baud with respect to milliseconds?

Tags: uart

[image]I am currently looking at TMP107 sensor. To read temperature, firstly 2 bytes are transmitted and after 1.5 baud, temperature value is received. I can not calculate baud rate. (I have used 115200 baud for UART)

edit: I uploaded read operation of sensor.

Comment: "after 1.5 baud" does not make sense. baud is bits per second, a unit of data flow. But "after 1.5 X" suggests that X is a unit of time

Comment: @MSalters, it makes, but involves non-standard terminology. Anyway, 1 baud == 1 period of clock signal. 1.5 — 1.5 clocks respectively. The odd number of edges suggests that if it starts with "1" it stops on "1" and vice versa.

Comment: Is it UART or USART? Or maybe it uses SPI? In any case if it's about Linux, use the driver from kernel.